# Удаление объекта Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть сфера и есть куб. Как сделать так, чтобы при столкновении с кубом сфера удалялась?

На куб повесил такой скрипт, но он удаляет сам куб:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    float posX, posY, posZ;
    posX = transform.position.x;
    posY = transform.position.y;
    posZ = transform.position.z;
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (collision.gameObject.name == "SPHERE_NAME") {
    Destroy(collision.gameObject);
}
```

или

```
if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("SPHERE_TAG") { //  if(collision.gameObject.tag == "SPHERE_TAG")
    Destroy(collision.gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверка не обязательна. В твоем случае код будет следующий

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    float posX, posY, posZ;
    posX = transform.position.x;
    posY = transform.position.y;
    posZ = transform.position.z;
    Destroy(collision.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: почему же проверка не обязательна? вот добавит он еще предметы (или просто тут упрощенно вопрос описал) и всё "Халк. Круши!"?

Comment: В вопросе не указано ограничение по тегу. Я изменил код чтобы удалялась сфера, зачем усложнять для человека?)

Comment: Затем, что это неверно.  Потому что на сцене может быть что угодно с коллайдером. даже банально земля или стена. И заранее человек обрекается на неправильную логику и внезапные проблемы.

Comment: Ну в общем я не спорю что с тегом будет верно.

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь